# How combine 2 forEach vanilla JS in DOM manipulation

Tags: javascript, for-loop, dom, foreach

I'm working on an exercise where I need to change the backgroundColor of the product if the price is > 3,00.
Here is what I've done so far. For some reason, if I'm changing the price color it will work perfectly but, when trying to change the div backgroundColor it will change for all the cards.

What I'm doing wrong?

Here the website: [https://www.monoprix.fr/courses/legumes-frais-mpx_c0000400?page=22]

Thanks

```
function exercise_3() {
    var price = document.querySelectorAll(".grocery-item__normal-price");
    let changePriceColor = 300;
    var block = document.querySelectorAll(".grocery-item-item");


    block.forEach( item => {

        price.forEach(price => {

             var changeColor = price.innerHTML.slice(0,4).replace(/,/g, '');

             ( changeColor > changePriceColor ) ? 
             item.style.backgroundColor = "red" : ''; (not working)

             ( changeColor > changePriceColor ) ? 
             price.style.color = "red" : ''; (working)
        })
    
    })
}


var numberOfPriceElements = 0;

// count elements on load
numberOfPriceElements = document.querySelectorAll(".grocery-item__normal-price").length;

document.addEventListener('scroll', (e) => {
    // if count of elements is more then do the function and save the amount to the variable. 
    if(document.querySelectorAll(".grocery-item__normal-price").length > numberOfPriceElements) {
        exercise_3();
        numberOfPriceElements = document.querySelectorAll(".grocery-item__normal-price").length;
    }
});

exercise_3();
```

Comment: Please never use the conditional operator an "inline `if`". If you're aiming to make your code shorter, then `if (<condition>) <what should happen>` is equivalent to `<condition> ? <what should happen> : ''` - in both cases `<condition>` and `<what should happen>` are the same so, with one time you add four characters `if ()` the other you add...four characters `? : ''`. Not to mention that by *repeating the condition* you've actually wrote more code in the end than `if (<condition>) { <thing 1>; <thing 2>; }`

Comment: Also, remember that you're asking people to read over your code. Take the time to make sure it's formatted in a way folks can actually read it instead of having indent issues on every line, and having lines that run off the page. [A well-formatted post goes a long way](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: What may be useful is to set a variable to the value of the condition; `var makeColorChange = changeColor > changePriceColor;` Then use that in each conditional operator, if you want to reset the background color: `item.style.backgroundColor = makeColorChange ? "red" : "";` as that appears to be what you actually want.

Comment: Along with that, `item.style.backgroundColor` will end up being set to whatever the last comparison between `changeColor` and `changePriceColor` turned out to be. That may be why it's not working...

Comment: it returns undefined @HereticMonkey
Anything is happening